# Replicating the formatting of a document

Tags: fonts, backgrounds

I was trying to replicate this document in Latex. Does anyone have an idea what fonts they are using and how they got the background colour on the side?

[image]

This is the code I have so far.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,legalpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[placement=top,position={0,0},angle=0,scale=1,hshift=-40,vshift=-22,]{background}

%\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=20cm]{tree}}}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}
\usepackage{xcolor}




\begin{document}

\section{Using packages}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent
This section illustrates the use of the amsfonts package.  Besides the itemize feature used, it also makes use of some special characters  which  can  easily  be  accessed;    for example the command {\textcolor{red}{clubsuit}} produces the  character  in  front  of  ”\textbf{\underline{Problem}}”  below.   Moreover,  math  symbols  illustrated here  are  commonly  used  during  any  math program, such as $\eta$.  Note that icons commands are named after the usual names, example  clubsuit  is  the  clubs  in  the  deck  of cards. \vspace{.25cm}\\ 
The   document   also   illustrates   the   ability    to    insert    images    as    background.This    is    achieved    using    the    package {\textcolor{red}{background.sty}}.  This package is includedin the download of the MikTex and or TexWorks  software.    While  running  the  pro-gram,  you  need  to  remove  the  graphicxpackage from the header of this tex document.\\
\indent
I used the following code to obtain the effect:
\vspace{2cm}

\noindent
\texttt{
\textbackslash usepackage[\\ 
\indent
placement=top, \\ \indent
position=\{0,0\},\\ \indent
angle=0,\\ \indent
scale=1,\\ \indent
hshift=-40,\\ \indent
vshift=-22,\\
]\{background\}\\backgroundsetup\{contents=\{\\ \indent includegraphics[width=1cm,\\
\indent height=20cm]\{tree\}\}\}\\}\vspace{.25cm}

\noindent Of course the coordinate (0, 0) positions thestart of image at top left corner.  From here,I altered the shifts to get the image at theright position.\\ \indent
The background package also allows you to color a certain region of the page with a background color of choice. \\ \indent Notice under ”Some Functions:”, the capital letter P is written as $ \mathbb{P} $.  This can be obtained using the command mathbb\{P\}.\\
\indent Remember  that  commands  carry  thebackslash before it. 

\end{multicols}


\section{An enumerated list using icons vs numbering}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\clubsuit$}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{\underline{Problem}}\\
There is none. \\
\LaTeX\ is easy.
\end{itemize}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\spadesuit$}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{\underline{Some Functions:}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $tan  x $

\item $ F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq x) = 
   \begin{cases} 0 & x > a \\
   \frac{x-a}{b-a} & a \geq x \geq b \\
   1 & b > x \\
   \end{cases}
$

\item $ \displaystyle{ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(2+\frac{1}{x} \right)^x} $
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\heartsuit$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\vartriangleright$}
\begin{itemize}
\item \underline{Some Math Symbols:}
\begin{itemize}
\item  $\eta$
\item $\sigma$
\item $\epsilon$
\item $\alpha $
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\diamondsuit$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\dag}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{\underline{Finite and Infinite Summations}}
\begin{itemize}

\item $ \sum  $ 
\item $ \int $
\item $ \oint $
\end{itemize} 

\end{itemize}

\end{multicols}

\section{Page Format}
For this document, I used legal paper versus the usual a4 paper.  Of course more styles can be added to a document to make it more visually attractive, but we must abide by Technical Writing principles, ”Simplicity is Sophistication”; that is, add details that highlight the document,do not create documents that highlight details.
\end{document} 
'''
```

Comment: It seems to me that the answers are already in the document you are showing, which corresponds to ...?

Comment: @SimonDispa sorry, I forgot to mention that I wanted it in LaTex. I only have the pdf and I wanted it as a tex file.

Comment: I understand. But the document is a guide that explains the font used and how to get the background. Did you try to write a minimum code with the code shown?

Comment: @SimonDispa yeah I did try to use it but it didn't come out as the picture illustrates

Comment: Please add your code to your question, so it will possible to correct it if necessary. What class does the guide recommends?

Comment: that document is obviously latex it says so in the text but for any pdf you can get the exact list of fonts using your odf readers font menu or the pdffonts command-line utility, you don't have to ask people to guess from a picture.

Comment: The text you show tells you how the background was made, it is including an image file `tree`

Comment: @SimonDispa I added it

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question essentially https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so that means I would need the image `tree` to get it?

Comment: yes of course, you need the same image.

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\\ \indent` to fake a paragraph, start a new paragraph  (with a blank line) you should almost never need `\indent` and hardly ever need `\\ ` or `\noindent` in text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the advice, any other tips?

Comment: `\displaystyle`  does not take an argument so it applies to the whole expression and the braces in `{ \lim_...}` do nothing useful. But for your actual question, isn't the tex source available from wherever you got the pdf?

Comment: If you have the PDF, it might be possible to extract the image from it via software such as Photoshop or Inkscape. However, note that the image might be copyrighted.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help you to get started.

Of course you should get a suitable "tree" for the side image.

[image: e]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt,legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[
placement=top,
position={0,0},
angle=0,
scale=1,
hshift=-44,
vshift=-15
]{background}

\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=30cm]{example-image-a}}}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\begin{document}
\section{Using packages}    
    
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent
This section illustrates the use of the amsfonts package.  Besides the itemize feature used, it also makes use of some special characters  which  can  easily  be  accessed;    for example the command {\textcolor{red}{clubsuit}} produces the  character  in  front  of  ``\textbf{\underline{Problem}}''  below.   Moreover,  math  symbols  illustrated here  are  commonly  used  during  any  math program, such as $\eta$.  Note that icons commands are named after the usual names, example  clubsuit  is  the  clubs  in  the  deck  of cards. 

The   document   also   illustrates   the   ability    to    insert    images    as    background.
This    is    achieved    using    the    package {\textcolor{red}{background.sty}}. 
This package is included in the download of the MikTex and or TexWorks  software.  
While  running  the  program,  you  need  to  remove  the  graphicx package from the header of this tex document.   

I used the following code to obtain the effect:

\columnbreak

\begin{verbatim}    
\usepackage[
placement=top, 
position={0,0},
angle=0,
scale=1,
hshift=-40,
vshift=-22,
]{background}
\backgroundsetup\{contents= {
includegraphics[width=1cm,
height=20cm]\{tree}}}
\end{verbatim}  

\noindent Of course the coordinate (0, 0) positions the start of image at top left corner.  From here, I altered the shifts to get the image at the right position.

The background package also allows you to color a certain region of the page with a background color of choice.

Notice under ``\textbf{Some Functions:}'', the capital letter P is written as
$\mathbb{P}$.  
This can be obtained using the command  {\color{red} \verb_mathbb{P}_}.

Remember  that  commands  carry  the backslash before it. 

\end{multicols}

\section{An enumerated list using icons vs numbering}

\end{document}
```